# Does pthread_join failure cause child process to be zombies?

Tags: c++, pthreads, zombie-process

I have a C++ pthread Thread invoking shell scripts using Popen.

What is observed in one case is that a pthread_join failure is caught (i.e pthread_join != 0) and the child process remains as zombie ( as per ps output).

This also causes the main program to hang.

Right now, I don't know why the pthread_join would fail, because it never did in other scenarios.

But I would like to know whether collecting the wait status of the child process spawned by Popen is part of thread_join. If so atleast I can be sure that the join failure is the root cause for the zombie and the program hang..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: yes, i had that in mind. yet to try as pthread_join is encapsulated as a common library. i had put it off for the next test..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling `popen`, there needs to be a corresponding call to `pclose`, otherwise the child process spawned by the `popen` call will remain in the zombie state. What might have happened is that the thread encountered an unhandled exception that caused `pclose` to not be called, resulting in a zombie and a "failed" result of `pthread_join`.

One solution is to make sure your code properly handles all possible exceptions.

Another solution would be to implement something similar to `popen()` but does not require `pclose()` to reap the zombie. This can be accomplished by using a *double fork*. You call `fork()`, then call it again before calling `exec()`. The parent process allows the intermediate child process to exit and be reaped with `wait4()`. The grandchild process can now exit without leaving a zombie since it will be reaped by the `init` process. To create a communication channel between the grandchild and parent, use `pipe()` as `popen()` does, or `socketpair()` if you need bidirectional communication. Use `dup2()` in the grandchild process to allow your choices of `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` to be redirected through the pipe or socket before calling `exec()`.

Comment: hmm that seems to make sense. because this join failure happens only when an underlying socket raises exception. but the try-catch catches the join failure.. I will check whether it is the pclose case and update the condition.

Comment: I have one doubt. If my main process has a signal handler for SIGCHLD and implements a wait, won't the zombie be removed even if join fails?

Comment: i accept your answer as that helped me nail the problem. The previous thread whose exception was handled after it joined was left in a list which was traversed again for joining when the current thread finished. Joining again causes failure, and hence this thread is never joined, leaving the zombie process and process hanging.. thanks :)