# Situations when `pthread_join` can fail / not invoked and cause zombie threads

Tags: c, pthreads

From: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html

Failure to join with a thread that is joinable (i.e., one that is not detached), produces a "zombie thread". Avoid doing this, ...

How can I avoid doing this? I don't get it, because when I try to join with a thread, why would I deliberately want to fail?

Comment: You can avoid this by *not doing it.*

Comment: "*Failure to join ...*" means "*Not calling `pthread_join()` ...*".

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870599/does-pthread-join-failure-cause-child-process-to-be-zombies) link too

Comment: Should say *neglect* to join. "Failure" is overloaded in computing.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the man page means that if your application does not join a joinable thread after it terminates, but just forgets it, then the terminated thread becomes a zombie thread, and zombies are bad.

That is, *failure* here means *deliberately not performing*.

Comment: So is joining a better or best thing to do? Why would I want to join a thread that has terminated. I mean why is it required?

Comment: Joining a terminated thread releases system resources that are allocated by this terminated thread (when the thread terminates, the system still keeps it's exit status, and I guess thread id and other thread-related data are also kept until 'join'.) Consider `pthread_join` as destructing the thread object. Not joining will cause a leak of system resources.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Failure to join with a thread that is joinable (i.e., one that is not
 detached), produces a "zombie thread".  Avoid doing this
```

It indicates you should make sure you handle all possible cases that can lead to `pthread_join` not being called for a thread. (and cause a zombie)

Further it states that,

```
   There is no pthreads analog of waitpid(-1, &status, 0), that is,
   "join with any terminated thread".
```

<sub>See [waitpid](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Process-Completion.html) here. and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377811/tracking-the-death-of-a-child-process) too</sub>

You don't have any functions like in case of processes to check, so its better you avoid missing a call to `pthread_join` by properly handling cases in your code.

Comment: Can you explain with an example of some code. I cannot understand what do you mean by "you should make sure you handle all possible cases that can lead to pthread_join not being called for a thread. (and cause a zombie)"

Answer (score 0):

To avoid create "Zombie Thread"
you need do these things:

1. do not use detached thread.
2. make sure you have cancel_point in the right location in the thread routine.
3. make sure your thread routine has an exit code.

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to avoid zombies is to use the detached thread feature. Invoke `pthread_detach(pthread_self())` in the thread entrypoint function, or invoke `thid = pthread_create(...); pthread_detach(thid)` when creating the thread.